# Clone registrated customers to an other database Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am beginner on prestashop , I want to clone registrated customers in an other database , other than prestashop DB , the relation between the two tables is user_id in prestashop db and prestashop_id_user in my db , so does any one have an idea how to process (create a new module or use existing one ...)

Comment: Finally , I have , the answer , you shoud install a hook to update table customer in database with new fields , then user curl inside an action hook (afterAdd)